# Make table size same to the div

Tags: html, css, html-table, position, overlap

This is difficult for me to ask.
In short: my div overlaps (gets outside the table). I want the table to be sized according to the div.

When I'm trying to add a footer, the content overlaps it. Here is the code:

Here is the page: [page](http://www.turdidesigns.com/bin/ebay/hdauto/shop.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the `.middle` css class sets the height of the center content to `25px` The footer is therefore positioned related to the menu table content on the left. 
If you remove the `25px` from the css class the div should work as you expect

Answer (score 0):

Ok I will suggest you rewrite your site because it's total mess, use my template for starters:

```
<div class="wrap">
<div class="header"></div>
<div class="body">
    <div class="left-side"></div>
    <div class="center"></div>
    <div class="right-side"></div>
</div>
<div class="footer"></div>
</div>​
```

And css:

```
.wrap{
    width: 400px;
    height: 500px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.header{
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #dddddd;
}
.body{
    width: 100%;
    height: 350px;
}
.left-side{
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    width: 20%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #eeeeee;
}
.center{
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    width: 60%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #cccccc;
}
.right-side{
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    width: 20%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #eeeeee;
}
.footer{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #dddddd;
}
​
```

Here is live example in [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mdjmc/10/)

Comment: hi, are you sure this will work fine when put to ebay, because as I know it's based on tables?? Thanks for the comment's. I don't want to have external CSS and stuff on my own server.

Answer (score 0):

well, @Arturas.. I kinda agree with @skmasq for your website. I think it'll be better if you're not using `table` for the layout. but, if still want to use your current website source code, try to delete the `.middle`'s height property. because you set it fixed 25px, but the content is overload, that's why it's overlapping.

Comment: hi, Well this will not be a web site. It's a template for ebay, so I need to use table's. But thanks for advice.